# How can i make matrix 20*20 with solution (python)

Tags: python

```
mx = 20
my = 20
t0_matrix = np.array((mx, my))
for i in range(mx):
  for j in range(my):
      t0_matrix[i][j] = u(0, i, j, mx, my)
      print(t0_matrix)
```

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
> last)
>  in ()
> 4 for i in range(mx):
> 5   for j in range(my):
> ----> 6       t0_matrix[i][j] = u(0, i, j, mx, my)
> 7       print(t0_matrix)
>
> TypeError: 'numpy.int64' object does not support item assignment

I want to get the answers as matrix. 20*20 How can i fix this problem?

Comment: What `u(0, i, j, mx, my)` does?

Answer (score 2):

The function `np.array` takes as argument a list (of lists...) that is converted into a numpy array. You can instead use the function `np.zeros` to intialize your t0_matrix, e.g. by doing `t0_matrix = np.zeros(shape=(mx, my))`

The problem is that your code is going to result in t0_matrix = [mx, my] = [20, 20], so the content of your array is mx and my